# select2 + large number of records

Tags: jquery-select2, large-data, largenumber

I am using select2 dropdown. It's working fine for smaller number of items. 
But when the list is huge (more than 40000 items) it really slows down. It's slowest in IE.

Otherwise simple Dropdownlist works very fast, till 1000 records. Are there any workarounds for this situation?

Comment: This would probably be better received on select2 bug tracker?

Comment: Ok thanks, domen well i resolved issue with below code

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer. This can be valuable to future users.

Comment: Yes definitely it is, domen, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
///////////////**** Jquery Code *******///////////////
var CompanypageSize = 10;

function initCompanies() {
        var defaultTxtOnInit = 'a';
        $("#DefaultCompanyId").select2({
            allowClear: true,
            ajax: {
                url: "/SignUpTemplate/GetCompanies",
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                global: false,
                data: function (params) {
                    params.page = params.page || 1;
                    return {
                        keyword: params.term ? params.term : defaultTxtOnInit,
                        pageSize: CompanypageSize,
                        page: params.page
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (data, params) {
                    params.page = params.page || 1;
                    return {
                        results: data.result,
                        pagination: {
                            more: (params.page * CompanypageSize) < data.Counts
                        }
                    };
                },
                cache: true
            },
            placeholder: {
                id: '0', // the value of the option
                text: '--Select Company--'
            },
            width: '100%',
            //minimumInputLength: 3,
        });
    }


//////////******* Have to initialise in .ready *******///////////////

 $(document).ready(function () {

        initCompanies();
    });

//////////******* C# code :: Controller is : SignUpTemplateController************/////

public JsonResult GetCompanies(string keyword, int? pageSize, int? page)
    {
        int totalCount = 0;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(keyword))
        {
            List<Companies> listCompanies = Companies.GetAll(this.CurrentTenant, (keyword ?? string.Empty).Trim(), false, 11, page.Value, pageSize.Value, ref totalCount, null, null, null, null, null).ToList();
            var list = listCompanies.Select(x => new { text = x.CompanyName, id = x.CompanyId }).ToList();

            return Json(new { result = list, Counts = totalCount }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: I have find the answer on my own.
Just by use the Select2 with Ajax.
Its Like Select2 + Pagging .

what i have done is, 
C# : getting PagedList with pagenumber and pageValue, which returns text,id
Jquery: used select 2 pagging events
HTML: used simple select 2 html

Comment: <section class="col col-4">
                           <label class="select">
                              <select id="DefaultCompanyId" name="DefaultCompanyId" class="select2">
                              </select>
                           </label>
                       </section>